# Can Delegated External User Administrators assign Roles to the Users?

Tags: community, administration, customer-community, experience-cloud

I have fully setup delegated external user administration but I want the delegated admin to have the ability to specify the role of the new user in the community.

The admin should have the ability to choose between 'Manager' or  'User' (2 roles for this customer community).

Because the admin is not seeing an option to specify the role, the new community users are always created with the 'User' role.

I have not been able to find any documentation specifying the delegated admin should/should not have the ability to specify the role of the new community user.

Is this possible?

[Delegated External User Administration Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_DPUA.htm&type=5)

I would like the 'Role' field added to the following layout (reference Community Member Page Layouts on the User object) but the Role field is not an option.
[image: This image shows the standard layout for Delegated External User Administration]